# Ansible: How to set password for a user? Having trouble encrypting the password

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm trying to setup ansible. The issue I'm having is that my **authentication is failing when I use an encrypted password**. I do *not* want to use the root user, but would like to use the user account "t0142734". Now, **where do I put the password** for this user? And **how do I encrypt the password?**

Here is what I did:

1. I have my **hosts** file (/etc/ansible/hosts) set up like this:

   ```
   [devservers]
   pses00top
   pses16top
   pses99top

   [customerLabs]
   pses21top
   pses25top

   [allLabs]
   pses00top
   pses16top
   pses99top
   pses21top
   pses25top
   ```
2. And I have my **playbook** (/etc/ansible/playbooks/test.yml) set up like this:

   ```
   ---
   - hosts: devservers
     remote_user: t0142734
     user: t0142734
     vars:
       password: $1$SomeSalt$xAFXP474fwpr2MobtwE.5/
     tasks:
      - user: name=t0142734 password={password} comment="Katie" ssh_key_file=/home/t0142734/.ssh/id_rsa
      - name: ping test
        ping:
   ```
3. I used the following to **generate the encrypted password**:

   ```
   python -c 'import crypt; print crypt.crypt("This is my Password", "$1$SomeSalt$")'
   ```
4. And I setup my ansible configuration file **ansible.cfg** (/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg) like this:

   ```
   inventory      = /etc/ansible/hosts
   host_key_checking = False
   remote_user = t0142734
   ```
5. I **run my playbook** like the following:

   ```
   ansible-playbook test.yml
   ```
6. The **error** i'm getting is the following:

   ```
   <pses25top> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: t0142734
   <pses25top> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -vvv -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey
   -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=t0142734 -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r -tt pses25top '/bin/sh -c '"'"'( umask 22 && mkdir -p "` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1462469008.44-66881249426265 `" && echo "` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1462469008.44-66881249426265 `" )'"'"''

   pses25top | UNREACHABLE! => { 
       "changed": false,  
       "msg": "SSH encountered an unknown error. The output was:\nOpenSSH_7.2p2, OpenSSL 1.0.2g-fips  1 Mar 2016\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndebug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *\r\ndebug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master\r\ndebug1: Control socket \"/root/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-pses25top-22-t0142734\" does not exist\r\ndebug2: resolving \"pses25top\" port 22\r\ndebug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0\r\ndebug1: Connecting to pses25top [10.76.115.151] port 22.\r\ndebug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug1: fd 3 clearing O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug1: Connection established.\r\ndebug3: timeout: 9999 ms remain after connect\r\ndebug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0\r\ndebug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type 1\r\ndebug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory\r\ndebug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1\r\ndebug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0\r\ndebug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2\r\ndebug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.1\r\ndebug1: match: OpenSSH_7.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000\r\ndebug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug1: Authenticating to pses25top:22 as 't0142734'\r\ndebug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file \"/root/.ssh/known_hosts\"\r\ndebug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /root/.ssh/known_hosts:23\r\ndebug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from pses25top\r\ndebug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521\r\ndebug3: send packet: type 20\r\ndebug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 20\r\ndebug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received\r\ndebug2: local client KEXINIT proposal\r\ndebug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c\r\ndebug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa\r\ndebug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc\r\ndebug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc\r\ndebug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1\r\ndebug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1\r\ndebug2: compression ctos: zlib@openssh.com,zlib,none\r\ndebug2: compression stoc: zlib@openssh.com,zlib,none\r\ndebug2: languages ctos: \r\ndebug2: languages stoc: \r\ndebug2: first_kex_follows 0 \r\ndebug2: reserved 0 \r\ndebug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal\r\ndebug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1\r\ndebug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519\r\ndebug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com\r\ndebug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com\r\ndebug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1\r\ndebug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1\r\ndebug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com\r\ndebug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com\r\ndebug2: languages ctos: \r\ndebug2: languages stoc: \r\ndebug2: first_kex_follows 0 \r\ndebug2: reserved 0 \r\ndebug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org\r\ndebug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256\r\ndebug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: zlib@openssh.com\r\ndebug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: zlib@openssh.com\r\ndebug1: kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org need=64 dh_need=64\r\ndebug1: kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org need=64 dh_need=64\r\ndebug3: send packet: type 30\r\ndebug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 31\r\ndebug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:PV4k4IbhF+EJn096uBoQ44xkmK4meIQWKGkIV00dD44\r\ndebug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file \"/root/.ssh/known_hosts\"\r\ndebug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /root/.ssh/known_hosts:23\r\ndebug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from pses25top\r\ndebug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file \"/root/.ssh/known_hosts\"\r\ndebug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /root/.ssh/known_hosts:23\r\ndebug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 10.76.115.151\r\ndebug1: Host 'pses25top' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.\r\ndebug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:23\r\ndebug3: send packet: type 21\r\ndebug2: set_newkeys: mode 1\r\ndebug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks\r\ndebug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent\r\ndebug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 21\r\ndebug2: set_newkeys: mode 0\r\ndebug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks\r\ndebug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received\r\ndebug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa (0x560d1b74fae0)\r\ndebug3: send packet: type 5\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 6\r\ndebug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth\r\ndebug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received\r\ndebug3: send packet: type 50\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 51\r\ndebug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password\r\ndebug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password\r\ndebug3: preferred gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey\r\ndebug3: authmethod_lookup publickey\r\ndebug3: remaining preferred: ,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey\r\ndebug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey\r\ndebug1: Next authentication method: publickey\r\ndebug1: Offering RSA public key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa\r\ndebug3: send_pubkey_test\r\ndebug3: send packet: type 50\r\ndebug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 51\r\ndebug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password\r\ndebug2: we did not send a packet, disable method\r\ndebug1: No more authentication methods to try.\r\nPermission denied (publickey,password).\r\n", 
           "unreachable": true
       }
   ```
7. When I try to connect **without using the encrypted password** (comment out the password var in the playbook), and I use the command `ansible all -vvvv -m ping --ask-pass`, **it works**!!! I get this back:

   ```
   pses25top | SUCCESS => {
       "changed": false, 
       "invocation": {
           "module_args": {
               "data": null
           }, 
           "module_name": "ping"
       }, 
       "ping": "pong"
   }
   ```

**So, when I try to use my encrypted password it does not work. When I make ansible prompt me for a password, it works. Any help?**

Also, I'm not sure what to do with the "salt". Do I need to include it somewhere?

The version of Ansible I am using is **ansible 2.0.1.0**

Resources:

- [Ansible User Module Docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/user_module.html)
- [Ansible FAQ about generating encrypted passwords](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/faq.html#how-do-i-generate-crypted-passwords-for-the-user-module)
- [Ansible Configuration File Docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html)
- [Ansible Inventory Docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html)

Comment: Have a look at [creating-a-new-user-and-password-with-ansible](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19318368/4175647)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear, what are you trying to do. It seems that you are trying to authenticate using password before setting password (your `remote_user` and `user: name` are equal).

Are you creating a new user "t0142734"? Then you don't have this `remote_user` account yet! You have to use another user for that purpose (root for instance).

Are you changing password of an existing user "t0142734.? Then you have to authenticate somehow else, because current password of this user must differ from a new one.

So as to login you can use `ask-pass`, or password + `ansible-vault`, or `ssh keys`.

Do simple test. Try to set up user's password via Ansible and then just login using `ssh t0142734@pses00top`. Without `authorised_keys` configured you should be asked to enter password. In case you succeed — everything is done properly