# Ansible Inventory : Change password of the hosts after a few tasks in a playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have the following inventory

```
[lites]
8m007 ansible_ssh_pass=welcome1 ansible_connection=ssh ansible_ssh_user=root ansible_ssh_common_args='-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null'
8m013 ansible_ssh_pass=welcome1 ansible_connection=ssh ansible_ssh_user=root ansible_ssh_common_args='-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null'
```

My playbook looks like this

```
---
  - name: Image Server(s)
    hosts: lites
    gather_facts: no
    tasks:
    - name: Wait for 5 minutes
      pause:
        minutes: 5

    - name: Create mount directory
      file:
        path: "{{mountpt}}"
        state: directory
```

I want to change the password of the hosts 8m007 and 8m013 to "welcome2" after task "Create mount directory", can it be done without much of changes ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a new user and password with Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19292899/creating-a-new-user-and-password-with-ansible)

Comment: Use `set_fact` and set a new value for `ansible_password`. Note1: this will survive until end of playbook (or end of fact cache TTL if you have a persistent backend). Note2: `ansible_ssh_pass` is an alias for upward compatibility but is deprecated.